# What do you call a piece of dead skin next to your nail bed?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a piece of dead skin next to the nail bed of your finger?

Usually this piece of dead skin is rather thin — and it isn’t very wide, either, but the longer it is, the more it hurts. I usually start noticing these pieces of dead skin when one of them gets to be about half an inch long and hurts whenever I touch it.

Is there a better way to describe this piece of dead skin? I’ve tried to find a picture of it on the internet to link to, but I found some rather disturbing pictures instead.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate.  The answer to this question (***hangnail***) does not appear anywhere on the linked question or answers.

Comment: Yep, it's a hangnail.

Comment: Half an ***inch*** long?!? When I get them, they hurt like a mofo after they reach about 2 mm in length! Half an inch would be down past what Wikipedia informs me is called the distal interphalangeal joint! Argh!

Comment: Before it splits off from the rest of the skin and pulls away and begins to hurt, the sliver of skin is, I believe, called a _cuticle_.

Comment: i think it is not dead skin, but torn skin.

Comment: it is not intuitive to name torn skin "hangnail". probably there are other dialectal words. (this is not critique comment, but like additional info comment).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually refer to various bits of skin off the side of my nail as ***hangnails***, regardless of whether it is skin or part of my nail itself. But, from [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/beauty/nails/treating-a-hangnail-topic-overview):

> A *hangnail* is the strip of skin that separates from the side of the cuticle.

I refer to WebMD rather than a dictionary in hopes that it will help you treat your pain.

If the skin was puffy and then cracked open, it may be the after math of a *popped blister* or *fungal infection*. You may want to visit a dermatologist.

Comment: I also same some gruesome images while looking that up. :o